# pre_get_posts not firing at all

Tags: custom-post-types, search, pre-get-posts

I'm trying to add a custom post type into the seach facility so that it searches those posts as well as the pages on a site.

I have seen the pre_get_posts function and have it set up like the below in my themes functions.php file but its not firing at all.  I have put get_current_screen() function in there to test but it doesn't return anything.

```
function searchAll($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'movie' ) );
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','searchAll');
```

I also tried to just have the $query->set('post_type', array( 'post', 'movie' ) ); line not in any of the if statements but nothing is happening.  What am I doing wrong?

Please help!

Comment: Function seems ok, it should work. Try adding `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'searchAll', 1 );`

Comment: `$query->is_search` should be `$query->is_search()`

Comment: Just tried, but no good! I'm thinking there must be some error in the theme somewhere.

Comment: Try `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'searchAll', 999 );`

Comment: Try @Milo's suggestion. `$query->is_search()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your functions.php.

```
function my_custom_get_posts( $query ) {
  if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
    return;

  if ( $query->is_search() ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'movie' ) );
  }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_get_posts', 1 );
```

Also make sure you do not have any other `pre_get_posts` action overwriting this function's effect.

Comment: *smacks-hand-against-head...  I didn't even think about if the function was already in use.  I checked, and it was, so just added my post type to the existing function.  Now it works. feel a bit silly now.

Comment: We all make fair share of such mistakes. :)